# Integrate google forms with custom content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am pretty much new to Google forms. I want to create a google form that will be a survey primarily. For each question I have to show a 3d model (threejs?) and a rating will be given on the model. So the primary content for each question is a 3d model and a text line related to the content. The user will then rate the loaded mesh. The idea is to collect data and use it for my research.

I saw one or two ways to approach this problem.

1. Either google should allow iframe content to load for each question
   with the question id or number passed as a GET/POST parameter to the
   iframe url
2. Or can i embed the google form in my hosting space? Does google
   forms have javascript support? To call a javascript method whenever
   a new question is loaded on the screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend build you own html form in the form of a webapp.  You'll have greater flexibility but you will also need to know Javascript and Google Apps Script to link it to a spreadsheet.  Start your reading [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

Comment: Why do you want to use google form for this since your requirements are all customized and doing data collection can be achieved by many database or platforms.

Comment: Many thanks @Cooper for this suggestion and I will look into it.

Comment: @Chris Chen, I agree that database is the final end point or solution to my requirement. Provided I would have had the time or knowledge to create a database that stores the answers do you think I would have looked into google forms in the first place?

Comment: Based on your description I'd suggest you to try to use https://firebase.google.com to make your project and yourself future prove. Good luck.

Comment: So far I was able to load the google form in an iframe and an onload function to trigger the loading of question on my webpage. Sadly, I am not able to find the current section/question number because of cross-domain policy of google-forms. Does someone know how to tackle this issue?